# Working with CellOjbects

Tags: front-end, cells

Suppose I have a text cell that contains the word "cat".  I can store this cell as a cell object into a variable called x.  How do I print x so that it appears as the original cell?  Essentially I am copy and pasting but I'm doing it via cell objects.

If I try pasting with

```
NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], x]
```

the output is

```
CellObject[487025]
```

I want the output to be the original cell as if I simply copied and pasted a cell.  Ideas?

Comment: Try `NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], NotebookRead@x]`

Comment: ahhh!  So simple.  Thank you!

Comment: "I can store this cell as a cell object into a variable called x." This phrasing suggests that there might be a misunderstanding. I just wanted to point out that a `CellObject` is better thought of as a handle to a cell that exists independently in a notebook rather than the cell itself.  It's a bit like a pointer in C.